# ZipKit and iOS5 - synthesized vs. user defined setter/getter

Tags: ios, zip

When compiling a project with ZipKit (https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home) with the latest iOS5, I see the following warnings:

*cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter*

Any ideas ?
The code in question is:

```
- (void) setInvoker:(id)i {
_invoker = i;
if (_invoker) {
    irtsIsCancelled = [self.invoker respondsToSelector:@selector(isCancelled)];
} else {
    irtsIsCancelled = NO;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Not really related to iOS 5 so I'll answer.

Is the `invoker` @property declared with `nonatomic`? probably not.

In which case the runtime is generating an atomic getter while you have written a non-atomic setter. The compiler is warning you about that.

Comment: Well it's not related to iOS 5 directly but this warning is new in LLVM 3.0 *I think*. The OP then probably saw the warning just when upgrading to the iOS 5 SDK.

Comment: @gcamp It's LLVM, but not new with 3.0 - it's been around since 1 _I think_

Comment: Yes, you're right it's really LLVM. Adding nonatomic to the @property declaration fixes it - thanks!